# How can I use this React component to collect form data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've created two components which together create a 'progressive' style input form. The reason I've chosen this method is because the questions could change text or change order and so are being pulled into the component from an array stored in a JS file called CustomerFeedback.

So far I've been trying to add a data handler function which will be triggered when the user clicks on the 'Proceed' button. The function should collect all of the answers from all of the rendered questions and store them in an array called RawInputData. I've managed to get this to work in a hard coded version of SurveyForm using the code shown below but I've not found a way to make it dynamic enough to use alongside a SurveyQuestion component. Can anybody help me make the dataHander function collect data dynamically?

Comment: Can you move your example to codesandbox for make me easier for help you?
Or short answer: you can use forwardRef+useImperativeHandle , that help easy and fast get data from child componets, but not the best approach for react, so it is recommended to use it more declaratively. And better solution use for example react-hook-form like nested forms and control from data by this library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There what I have done:

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-dew-37szi2?file=/src/InputForm.js:262-271

So, we can make it easier, you just can pass necessary data when call handler from props:

```
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  const handleNext = () => {
    props.clickHandler(props.reference, inputRef.current.value);
  };
```

And merge it at InputForm component:

```
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({});

  const handler = (thisIndex) => (key, value) => {
    if (thisIndex === currentIndex) {
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
      setInputData((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [key]: value
      }));
    }
  };

  // ...
    <Question
        // ...
        clickHandler={handler(question.index)}
      />
```

So, you wanted array (object more coninient I think), you can just save data like array if you want:

```
setInputData(prev => [...prev, value])
```

Initially, I thought you want to collect data on button clicks in the InputForm, but apparently you can do without this, this solution is simpler

**UPD**
Apouach which use useImperativeHandle:
If we want to trigger some logic from our child components we should create handle for this with help of forwarfRef+useImperativeHandle:

```
const Question = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  React.useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    {
      getData: () => ({
        key: props.reference,
        value: inputRef.current.value
      })
    },
    []
  );
```

After this we can save all of our ref in parent component:

```
  const questionRefs = React.useRef(
    Array.from({ length: QuestionsText.length })
  );

  // ...

  <Question
     key={question.id}
     ref={(ref) => (questionRefs.current[i] = ref)}
```

And we can process this data when we want:

```
  const handleComplete = () => {
    setInputData(
      questionRefs.current.reduce((acc, ref) => {
        const { key, value } = ref.getData();
        return {
          ...acc,
          [key]: value
        };
      }, {})
    );
  };
```

See how ref uses here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

I still strongly recommend use react-hook-form with nested forms for handle it

Comment: Hi there, I've implemented this solution and realised that I do actually want to collect the data when the button is clicked in the InputForm, how could I go about doing that?

Comment: I have updated the example